# Syntax highlighting thrown off by apostrophe in comment

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I noticed a bug in the syntax highlighting for Objective-C code. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623716/error-no-such-table-sqlite

The apostrophe in a comment in the second code block seems to confuse the highlighter:

[image: screenshot]

Oddly, when I paste the code here and manually tag it as Objective-C, it seems to work fine:

```objc
-(NSMutableDictionary *)getList:(NSString*)typeOfRequest{
//Declaration d'un objet SQLITE
sqlite3 *database;

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
const char *sqlStatement = NULL;
NSString *objectKey = nil;

//Declaration de notre String qui sera retourne
NSMutableDictionary *aromaArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
// Ouverture de la base de donnees
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    //Chaine de caracteres de la requete
    if ([typeOfRequest isEqualToString:@"aroma_huiles"]) {
        sqlStatement = "SELECT name_fr FROM aroma_huiles";
        objectKey = @"name_fr";
    }
    else if ([typeOfRequest isEqualToString:@"aroma_prop"]) {
        sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM aroma_prop";
        objectKey = @"nom_propriete_fr";
    }
    else {
        sqlStatement = "SELECT name_fr FROM aroma_huiles";
        objectKey = @"name_fr";
    }
    //Creation de l'objet statement
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    //Compilation de la requete et verification du succes
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        // Creation d'un dictionnaire des noms de colonnes
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [self indexByColumnName:compiledStatement];
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            //Assigne la valeur dans la chaine de caracteres
            char *tab;
            tab = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, [[dictionary objectForKey:objectKey] intValue]);
            NSString *final = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tab];
            NSString *finalUpperCase = [final capitalizedString];
            if (finalUpperCase != nil && finalUpperCase.length >0) {
                [array addObject:finalUpperCase];
            }
        }
        NSMutableArray *table = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        while (i < [array count]) {
            NSString *firstLetter = [array[i] substringToIndex:1];
            table = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            while (j < [array count]) {
                NSString *secondLetter = [array[j] substringToIndex:1];
                if ([secondLetter isEqualToString:firstLetter]) {
                    [table addObject:array[j]];
                }
                j++;
            }
            j = 0;
            [aromaArray setObject:table forKey:firstLetter];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else {
        //Envois une exception en cas de probleme de requete
        NSAssert1(0, @"Erreur :. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    // Finalisation de la requete pour liberer la memoire
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}
else {
    //Envois une exception en cas de probleme d'ouverture
    NSAssert(0, @"Erreur d'ouverture de la base de donnees");
}
//Fermer la base de donnees
sqlite3_close(database);

//Retourne la valeur
return aromaArray;
```

Comment: Bugs with the highlighter should be reported to the Google Code Prettify project.

Comment: You don't feel this is caused by writing French comments, and even posting that on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Arjan You really expect him to translate *all* of his comments to English before posting any code? Or do you just want to ban French people from posting on Stack Overflow? Also, English has contractions.

Comment: Yes, @Doorknob, I do expect that! If it's a useful comment, it should be translated into English before posting. If not useful, it should be removed, I feel. (And just to be sure: of course I know it's not limited to French.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the question you reference does not have any Objective C highlighting attached to it. Normally, an iOS question would just use the default highlighter and let Prettify interpret what the language is, but you have the SQLite3 tag on it, which is set to use `lang-sql`. So all of your code on that question is being highlighted as SQL code, which that obviously isn't.

Comment: Good catch! I saw the iOS tag, and thought that would default the question to Objective-C highlighting. I guess now, with Swift, that isn‘t a safe assumption.